# BNF notation of T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, bnf

Do you know where can I get the BNF (Backus Naur Form) notation for the latest version of T-SQL from. This is the microsoft version and I can't find anything for it. I found SQL2 The revised ISO standard [here](http://cuiwww.unige.ch/db-research/Enseignement/analyseinfo/SQL92/BNFindex.html) also called SQL92 but it seems to lack some features of microsoft's T-SQL

Comment: I don't believe that there is a published BNF for T-SQL.

Comment: Perhaps if you revised your question to why you wanted such a thing/what problem you were seeking to solve, it could be achieved without?

Comment: I'm developing something like intellisense for T-SQL (like RedGate's SQL Prompt). That's why I need the BNF notation in order to know what is the next available cosntruct/keyword.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out this btw?

[General Sql Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-dotnet.php)

They have enginered the notation from the ground up....

Comment: That is closed source which means: no BNF.

Answer (score 5):

I developed TSql grammar for ANTLR 4 in EBNF form. Check it in official [grammars repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql). It based on [msdn description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx).

Currently implemented syntax:

- Control of Flow ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx)).
- Cursors ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181441.aspx)).
- Data manipulation language (DML):

  - Delete ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)).
  - Insert ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)).
  - Select ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)).
  - Update ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)).
- Expressions ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx)).
- Predicates.
- Transactions ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx)).

And another syntax. Check grammar and [test files](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql/examples) for more detail.

Comment: repository links are broken

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've fixed links.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I just found [this](https://bitbucket.org/qps/tsql-grammar) grammar file hosted on bitbucket that can be used with [GOLD Parsing System](http://goldparser.org/).

Since you're looking for TSQL's BNF (I was too), and it doesn't really exist, this grammar is the next best thing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL-92 in BNF](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql2bnf.aug92.txt)

SQL Server 2005 is based on SQL-92 with some SQL-99 features and Microsoft's T-SQL extensions. Best I have found currently.

Let me know if you find a more up to date one.....

Comment: Microsoft uses [brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9719869/402322) to quote identifiers. This is far away from SQL-92.