# What is the difference between the backtick and the square bracket in SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I thought there would be another question about this but I was unable to find one. In MySQL with PHP I usually encapsulate my field names with backticks to mask any reserved names or characters. However, one of my colleagues has pointed out that this can also be achieved using square brackets. Excluding the fact that the backticks are not compatible with SQL server (apparently), what is the difference? Which should I use?

```
SELECT `username` FROM `users`
SELECT [username] FROM [users]
```

Comment: Are square brackets compatible with MySQL then? In SQL Server you can also use " if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is on. Dunno if that is valid in MySQL either.

Comment: The brackets are required if you use keywords or special chars in the column or database names. Also square brackets are the way to use a reserved word as a field name (for instance [date])

Comment: You are right to question, no they are not compatible. I assumed they were!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SQL Server/T-SQL uses square brackets (as well as MS Access), while MySQL uses backticks.

As far as I know, can [turn up in documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), or use in testing, square brackets are *not* valid for MySQL.  So if you need to enclose a keyword as a table name in SQL Server, use `[]`, and in MySQL use backticks, or double-quotes when `ANSI_QUOTES` is enabled.

[From the documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 - `[]` are pretty much unique to T-SQL, I'm not sure that any other flavours of SQL accept them.

Comment: That is very interesting, we both believed that square brackets could be used anywhere. We have just tested with MySQL and you are right! :-)

Comment: The square brackets in SQL Server are also used in Microsoft Access, where embedded spaces in column and table names are quite common. You need something that is fairly easy to type. Trying to work out how to type a backtick can be murder.

Comment: @BenCarey: square brackets can **only** be used in Microsoft products. But SQL Server and MySQL do allow the usage of the standard quoting character `"` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Both are non-standard ways to quote object names that should either be case-sensitive, are a reserved word or contain special characters that are not allowed otherwise.

The standard quoting character for such an identifier is a double quote. To be ANSI SQL compatible, you should use them:

```
SELECT "username" FROM "users"
```

But note that quoted identifiers are case-sensitive as per ANSI SQL. However both mentioned products do not obey to this requirement. Whether such an identifier is case-sensitive or not depends on a several (different) configuration settings in MySQL and the database collation in MS SQL Server.

Both DBMS can (and in my opinion should) be configured to accept the ANSI standard quote characters as well.

I would strongly recommend to avoid any object name that *requires* quoting. Using identifiers that do not require quoting will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: I absolutely avoid any field or table names that include reserved names or special characters, however, as I am writing an MsSQL class that may be used by people with little experience, I must cater for them to. Thus, I need to wrap each field and table with the square bracket to help prevent errors. As it does not use much more resources (if any), I might as well implement it