# Make SQL like DDL statements

Tags: mysql, sql, import, ddl

As I run `mysql -u root -p -D foo < bar.sql`

It keeps arguing about the syntax

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Article_Category]

The script is generated from a ERM so I would like to preserve it.

```
CREATE TABLE [Article_Category]
(
[idArticle] []  NOT NULL,
[idCartegory] []  NOT NULL
)
```

How can I import this one and get rid of the error?

Comment: You can get rid of the error by creating a properly formatted file that MySQL can understand, what your ERM generates is obviously wrong syntax for MySQL.

Comment: Remove the square brackets. They are invalid for an SQL identifier (although some DBMS blatently ignore the SQL standard and do allow it).

Comment: The brackets `[]` are MS SQL syntax. Did you use Entity Framework to generate the DDL? And do you mean *ORM* instead of *ERM*?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719869/what-is-the-difference-between-the-backtick-and-the-square-bracket-in-sql-statem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This square bracket syntax is specific to Microsoft's table server product. MySQL doesn't use it. Most ERMs have a setting for choosing the make and model of table server for which it should generate DDL.