# MySQL: Error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to execute a SQL statement in PHPMyAdmin but I'm getting an error stating:

```
Error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'
```

The SQL Statement is as follows:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FFT_DG_REC_4](
    [time] [bigint] NULL,
    [c1] [int] NULL,
    [c2] [int] NULL,
    [c3] [int] NULL,
    [c4] [int] NULL,
    [c5] [int] NULL,
    [c6] [int] NULL,
    [c7] [int] NULL,
    [c8] [int] NULL,
    [c9] [int] NULL,
    [c10] [int] NULL,
    [c11] [int] NULL,
    [c12] [int] NULL,
    [c13] [int] NULL,
    [c14] [int] NULL,
    [c15] [int] NULL,
    [c16] [int] NULL,
    [c17] [int] NULL,
    [c18] [int] NULL,
    [c19] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

How might I correct this statement to resolve the issue?

Comment: QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is related to MS-SQL

Comment: Dont think `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is available in MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is not available in MySQL. Also, I dont think you need that to be set for this `CREATE` statement.

You can just use

```
 CREATE TABLE FFT_DG_REC_4(
        time    bigint NULL,
        c1      int NULL,
        c2      int NULL,
        c3      int NULL,
        c4      int NULL,
        c5      int NULL,
        c6      int NULL,
        c7      int NULL,
        c8      int NULL,
        c9      int NULL,
        c10     int NULL,
        c11     int NULL,
        c12     int NULL,
        c13     int NULL,
        c14     int NULL,
        c15     int NULL,
        c16     int NULL,
        c17     int NULL,
        c18     int NULL,
        c19     int NULL)
```

Comment: Hm. Ok. I tried running it without it and it results in: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[dbo].[FFT_DG_REC_4](
    [time] [bigint] NULL,




http://pastebin.com/7G4KjQdL

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question (apologies - I'm very new to MySQL) 

I'm getting an error stating: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fuzz int,
d1 int , d2 int , d3 int , d4 int , d5 int , d6 int , d7 int , d8 in' at line 2 

When I attempt to execute: http://pastebin.com/WzmK15w1 - How might I avoid the error on:  fuzz int

Comment: You need to put the whole parameter list inside `(` and `)`. Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Ok. Thank You. I tried as you suggested: http://pastebin.com/8mhw1N2R

But it still seems to fail.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS

Declare fuzz2 int
set fuzz2=fuzz
declare row1 int
set row1=4

decla' at line 23 

http://pastebin.com/8mhw1N2R

Comment: Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html as creating a stored procedure in MySQL is different from SQL Server. You shoud be using `BEGIN.....END` in your stored procedure instead of `AS`

Comment: Ok. I truly appreciate your advice... I tried as you suggested - still getting an error when attempting to execute it. :(

http://pastebin.com/3xYb0YLT

Comment: I modified it to contain the BEING and END - but it still isn't working - any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Its `BEGIN` and `END`

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is a Transact-SQL setting, while you are probaly using MySQL with PhpMyAdmin. This setting is not available in MySQL, you need to use `ANSI_QUOTES` instead. Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719869/what-is-the-difference-between-the-backtick-and-the-square-bracket-in-sql-statem) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is related to T-SQL (SqlServer) and is not available in MySQL. Also, square brackets can only be used in Microsoft products, not in MySQL. Since `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` allow you to use quoting character ", the equivalent in MySQL is `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';`

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like MSSQL or MSAccess. Maybe MySQL accepts `[` and `]`, but I've never seen it used, and don't think it would accept "quoted" data types either.
This is how I would've written that CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FFT_DG_REC_4 (
    `time` BIGINT NULL,
    c1 INT NULL,
    c2 INT NULL,
    c3 INT NULL,
    c4 INT NULL,
    c5 INT NULL,
    c6 INT NULL,
    c7 INT NULL,
    c8 INT NULL,
    c9 INT NULL,
    c10 INT NULL,
    c11 INT NULL,
    c12 INT NULL,
    c13 INT NULL,
    c14 INT NULL,
    c15 INT NULL,
    c16 INT NULL,
    c17 INT NULL,
    c18 INT NULL,
    c19 INT NULL
);
```