# MySQL Transaction - Update 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form that requires a user to validate their email address, the link is sent to the user as

`http://app.myurl.org/h/activate.php?email=useremail%40gmail.com&key=80fddb7fa21dd2e2639ae5ec82b9d511&api=8a2d01d7411ec2488307744ddf070a4d`

The user is directed to activate.php

I am trying to get the `email`, `key`, and `api` from the url.

I am then trying to **update both the users table and the roster table**.

`wrightway_roster` table column to  update is `Activation`

`wrightway_users` table column to update is `groups`

They both pass the unique value of a MD5 random hash. Everything is working smooth, just not the TRANSACTION query.

```
<?php
include ('database_connection.php');
if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email'])) { $email = $_GET['email']; }
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32)) { $key = $_GET['key'];}
if (isset($_GET['api']) && (strlen($_GET['api']) == 32)) { $API = $_GET['api'];}
if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {
    mysqli_query($dbc, "START TRANSACTION");
    $result_activate_account = mysqli_multi_query($dbc,"
       UPDATE table_users SET groups=[99] WHERE(pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1;
       UPDATE wrightway_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1;
    ");
    if ($result_activate_account !== false) {
        mysqli_query($dbc, "COMMIT");
        echo '<div>You may now proceed.</div>';
    } else {
        mysqli_query($dbc, "ROLLBACK");
        echo '<div>Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.</div>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
} else {
    echo '<div>An Error Occurred.</div>';
}
?>
```

PHP is 5.4 Native

both `Activation` and `groups` are **VARCHAR**

These queries work, and do exactly what is intended.

`"UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups='[99]' WHERE(pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1;";`

`UPDATE wrightway_roster SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1";`

I was using a single query orignally for what I need it to do, I wrote the above to use Transactions.

```
if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {

     // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

     $query_activate_account = "UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups='[99]' WHERE(pinAPP_API ='$API') LIMIT 1;";

     $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account);

     // Print a customized message:
     if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) //if update query was successful
     {
     echo '<div>You may now proceed.</div>';

     } else {
     echo '<div>Oops !You could not be validated. Please recheck the link or contact your hiring manager.</div>';

     }

     mysqli_close($dbc);

    } else {
     echo '<div>An Error Occurred.</div>';
    }
```

Comment: You **can** have multiple statements in a transaction.

Comment: Activation *is* nullable?
But lik hd1 says, I would do twice a mysqli_query, and OR the outcome of those to decide whether to commit or rollback.

Comment: Yes, because its only used once and then the field is deprecated for that specific user.

Comment: I tried doing two separate queries and couldn't get it to work, so i was reading up on what to do on SO, and came across the recommendation to use this alternative. Give me a second and I will chop this up to write two, or at least where I was at when I ran into troubles.

Comment: What's that [99] mean? I've never used that notation myself.

Comment: I have a function that writes a permission value and it is [1],[2],... or [1,2,3]... etc.

Comment: Yes, but field groups is int? Then use 99?

Comment: DB column is set to VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it working. This is what I used, and works exactly as needed!

```
if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {
    mysqli_query($dbc);
    $verified = mysqli_query($dbc,"
       UPDATE tbl_users t1, tbl_roster t2 SET t1.groups='[22]', t2.prescreen='0' WHERE t1.API='$API' AND t2.API='$API' AND t2.prescreen='$key';
    ");
    if ($verified !== false) {
        mysqli_query($dbc);
        echo '<br><center><div class="success"></div>';

    } 
    else {
        mysqli_query($dbc);
        echo '<br><div class="validation"></div>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  } else {
    echo '<br><div class="error">An Error Occurred.</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't accept this syntax

```
UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups=[99] ...
                                  ^  ^
```

Maybe one of these would work better:

```
UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups=99 ...
UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups="99"
UPDATE wrightway_users SET groups="[99]"
```

Depending on your needs and the type of *groups*.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719869/what-is-the-difference-between-the-backtick-and-the-square-bracket-in-sql-statem) seems to corroborate that.

Comment: Thats kinda where I was leaning the issue may be, however I have other mysqli queries that I do and it has [#] and posts perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you used `"[#]"`?

Comment: Running a query with [99] like that gets me: /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[99] ... */
I too think the use of [] is the issue.

Comment: I must have the [] wrapped around the value. Give me a second, I think I may have it.

Comment: MySQL doesn't accept the `=[xx]` syntax, so maybe dreamweaver needs to be told to use `MySQL` and not `SQL server`? (DW settings)

Comment: Okay, so it updates the Activation to NULL, but does not update the table for users. I did an echo test of the value to confirm and this is what I get. `API: 8a2d01d7411ec2488307744ddf070a4d
You may now proceed.`

Comment: If it's really a transaction, all or none of the queries should be performed if there is an error. If you are using InnoDB and there is no error, that means the problem is in the Where/Limit part of the Users query. Try to run the *Update* query for users alone in the *mysql* command in a terminal, you'll see better what happens, and if any row is updated at all

Comment: @LeviZoesch So basically, quoting `[99]` from this answer was most of the solution..

Comment: Yes, now I am getting this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[99] WHERE(pinAPP_API ='8a2d01d7411ec2488307744ddf070a4d') LIMIT 1; UPDA' at line 1` @ringø

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the mysqli_begin_transaction(), mysqli_rollback() and mysqli_commit() functions instead of calling begin transaction within mysqli_query()?

Documentation:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your error isn't somewhere else?, like those brackets arround the 99?

Im getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '[33] where id=1' at line 1
```

You can use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to check the last error.