# how to sort a column in mysql and get the sorted value of another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three fields,

```
id          (int)
shortnameid (varchar)
name        (varchar)
```

`name` contains both number and string for e.g:(01.john)

I need to sort the table as ASC by using `id` and get the sorted order of `name` column (after sorting by `id`).
This returns sorted number in serious:

```
SELECT * FROM  `tablename` ORDER BY  `tablename`.`id` ASC
```

But i need the sorted value (after sort the table by `id`) of `name` column.

Comment: what do you mean "this returns sorted number in serious" ?

Answer (score 1):

add name column to order by

```
SELECT * FROM  `tablename` ORDER BY  `tablename`.`id` ASC,`tablename`.`name`;
```

Comment: but i need name column ,it must sorted by id.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

```
select `name`
FROM 
`tablename`
ORDER BY `tablename`.`id` ASC
```

will return the list of `name` only, sorted by `id` ASC

If you want it sorted by `name` too, then:

```
select `name`
FROM 
`tablename`
ORDER BY `tablename`.`id` ASC, `tablename`.`name`
```

If this or the other answer is not what you are looking for then you need to restate your question.

Comment: this will not run in mysql.. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9719904/3876138 on square brackets ..

Answer (score 0):

First .. your design is wrong .. you do not satisfy [1 Normal Form](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) - that is do not mix multiple informations in one column..

You can make primary key of two columns (if id is not unique) at the same time:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, name)
```

You do not need to create extra column to have something unique..

---

Moreover the other answers are correct.. or noone understands what you want.

This is what you get by your query:

```
1 Bill 1.Bill
2 AAA 2.AAA
2 ZZZ 2.ZZZ
2 BBB 2.BBB
3 AAA 3.AAA
```

By doing the Mahesh Madushanka query you get:

```
1 Bill 1.Bill
2 AAA 2.AAA
2 BBB 2.BBB
2 ZZZ 2.ZZZ
3 AAA 3.AAA
```

What else do you want to achieve?

**UPDATE**

Do you want something like this (according to given example data above)?

```
id  |  names          | .... |
-----------------------
1   | "Bill"          |
2   | "AAA, BBB, ZZZ" |
3   | "AAA"           |
```

Comment: sort by Ascending  order of id and get the column (name) which is order by id(ascending order).then i will insert the to a drop down list of my application

Comment: @srirams your english makes it really hard to understand what you mean (I am not native English speaker too..). Just guessing but: Do you want list of all names concatenated in one string for each id - and these column lists are given to you in order of id? I will update answer - but please give us some example on mysql output..

Comment: i want to sort by names s.no  first three letters for Example 01.apple,02.mango and so no.. 110.pineapple.here i need to sort by first three letters (numeric values).but in data base it is in varchar type.i m new  to sql qwery.help me to sort.@ otopolsky

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the rather arcane syntax:

```
update table name
    set id = (select cnt
                    from (select count(*) as cnt
                          from table Name Name2
                          where Name2.shortnameid >= table name.shortnameid
                         )
                   )
```