# SQL syntax error has occurred

Tags: mysql, sql-server, perl, delimiter

Here is my simple query:

```
          my $SQLp = "SELECT MAX([PawnPayments].[CreationTimeDate]) as MaxTransDate
                FROM [PawnSafeDBCE].[dbo].[PawnPayments]
                INNER JOIN [PawnSafeDBCE].[dbo].[PawnPaymentDetails]
                ON [PawnPayments[.[PaymentID] = [PawnPaymentDetails].[PaymentID]
                WHERE [PawnPaymentDetails].[TicketID[ = '$TicketID'
                AND [PawnPaymentDetails].[StoreID] ='$StoreID'
```

Note that query is written on Perl engine. I keep receiving an error that says:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[PawnPayments].[CreationTimeDate]) as MaxTransDate:"

I believe the error has to do with the bracket notation, but unfortunately, I am having to use this style due to a poorly constructed 3rd party table. Any help? Am I missing something obvious?

Huge EDIT: The table I am querying is actually on a SQL server, not a MySQL server! My database runs on the MySQL server, but this 3rd party database runs on an older version of Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Check the syntax near `ON [PawnPayments[.[PaymentID] = [PawnPaymentDetails].[PaymentID]` and `WHERE [PawnPaymentDetails].[TicketID[ = '$TicketID'` Why you have open brackets here ?

Comment: You are trying SQL-server syntax on a MySQL server. Brackets are SQL-server 's escape method. And dbo is a object that only works in SQL-server... And your code look to be vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: Mysql does not have bracket notation it has back tick notation

Comment: Thank you for sharing that insight. I completely overlooked that syntax issue. Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Would that necessitate that I rewrite the query with backticks?

Comment: Only if you want it to work.

Comment: Your error message clearly says MySQL. So whereever you think there is an MSSQL server involved, you are not talking to it. Also, don't put variables into your SQL. Use DBI's placeholders instead.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719869/what-is-the-difference-between-the-backtick-and-the-square-bracket-in-sql-statem

Comment: If the 3rd party software you are using only supports Microsoft SQL Server, and can't be configured to use standard identifier delimiters (like with [SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql)), then you can't use it with MySQL.

Comment: Also I see your query has another Microsoft SQL Server feature: `[PawnSafeDBCE].[dbo].[PawnPayments]` uses the `Database.Schema.Table` notation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server), but MySQL doesn't support that. MySQL only supports `schema.table`. So your query won't work on MySQL even if you fix the square brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you have all those square brackets around your table and column names, but they aren't necessary and they aren't standard SQL. That's what is causing your syntax error.

```
my $SQLp = "SELECT MAX(PawnPayments.CreationTimeDate) as MaxTransDate
            FROM PawnSafeDBCE.dbo.PawnPayments
            INNER JOIN PawnSafeDBCE.dbo.PawnPaymentDetails
            ON PawnPayments.PaymentID = PawnPaymentDetails.PaymentID
            WHERE PawnPaymentDetails.TicketID = '$TicketID'
            AND PawnPaymentDetails.StoreID ='$StoreID'";
```

I'll also add that having variables interpolated in your SQL statement like that is potentially leaving you open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). Far better to use bind points in your SQL and use extra arguments to `execute` to fill in the values (assuming you're using DBI).

```
my $SQLp = "SELECT MAX(PawnPayments.CreationTimeDate) as MaxTransDate
            FROM PawnSafeDBCE.dbo.PawnPayments
            INNER JOIN PawnSafeDBCE.dbo.PawnPaymentDetails
            ON PawnPayments.PaymentID = PawnPaymentDetails.PaymentID
            WHERE PawnPaymentDetails.TicketID = ?
            AND PawnPaymentDetails.StoreID = ?";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQLp);
$sth->execute($TicketID, $StoreID);
```

**Update:** As [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) points out in a comment, the `database.schema.table` syntax makes no sense in a MySQL database. So I think you're a little confused. The error message you are getting definitely mentions MySQL, so you're connecting to a MySQL server, using DBD::MySQL - but perhaps you should be connecting to an MSSQL server instead.

It might be useful if you showed us your database connection code - the call that sets up your `$dbh` (or equivalent) variable.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the potential injection attacks. I have never been exposed to this information. I will try this method now.

Comment: The `Database.Schema.Table` syntax is not supported by MySQL either.

Comment: @BillKarwin: Good point. I've updated my answer. I think the OP is rather confused!

Comment: I think they're just using a Perl app that is clearly designed for Microsoft SQL Server, and they're trying to use it with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are querying a MS SQL database, but the error message clearly says you are using a MySQL database or a MySQL database driver.

If you are querying a MS SQL database, fix your connection string.

If you are querying a MySQL database, use a MySQL-compatible query. MySQL uses backticks to quote identifiers (not square brackets like MS SQL).

```
[PawnPayments].[CreationTimeDate]
```

should be

```
`PawnPayments`.`CreationTimeDate`
```

---

Note that your code suffers from injection bugs due to incorrect quoting of value inserted into the SQL query. (It's not good enough just to put quotes around the values!) These can cause your code to fail, and they could make you vulnerable to injection attacks. Fix the quoting, or use replaceable parameters.